# Where I can see all orders from google in-app purchase?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

I collect data when a user makes a purchase, and through a long time, I get 2 types of the order:

#### Type 1:

```
{  
   "orderId":"GPA.3377-3357-xxxx-xxxxx",
   "packageName":"com....",
   "productId":"pro",
   "purchaseTime":1560140153031,
   "purchaseState":0,
   "developerPayload":"nSOaKlC9VhhHIubsmjYIAfFqbTDoch3s",
   "purchaseToken":"nepgigljmob...aM-YBMag"
}
```

#### Type 2:

```
{  
   "orderId":"7222657463922129650.93244460976xxxxx",
   "packageName":"com...",
   "productId":"pro",
   "purchaseTime":1560315013656,
   "purchaseState":0,
   "developerPayload":"7Yk8blm0CyUCpoIIzsvUqAsp4u2MNAZg",
   "purchaseToken":"nsmzlsnhvzir...YLzUCf"
}
```

I usually receive Type 1 and I can see it in Order Management of Goolge Play Console. But sometimes, I receive Type 2, and they not shown in Order Management. I'm finding the place I can see Type 2 and get payment. Thank you for your help!